# What's the 'non-fragile methods' in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I heard something unknown *non-fragile methods* in Objective-C. What's this?

Comment: I've only heard of (non-)fragile ivars and (non-)fragile base classes. http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?WhatIsNonFragileInstanceVariables

Answer (score 2):

There’s no such thing as non-fragile methods in Objective-C.

On the other hand, non-fragile instance variables are a mechanism that allows the layout of a class to be modified whilst keeping compatibility with code that isn’t aware of the layout change.

This is useful for [modifying classes in a framework without affecting subclasses residing outside of the framework](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html), and it also allows [class extensions to define instance variables, including declared properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784875/does-a-private-property-create-an-private-instance-variable/5786228#5786228).