# Get an ivar or property from a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Can we get an `ivar` or a `property` from a `NSString` like we can get a `class` from a `NSString` with the function `NSClassFromNSString()` ?

Comment: Just wondering: what would you need this for? What use is it?

Comment: Yes, I could change my design pattern but I just want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any properties you can just use `[object valueForKey:myString]` and it'll be done. This can also find ivars in certain situations.

Comment: I’ve posted an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5784875/557219) showing how to obtain ivars using the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of functions in the Objective-C Runtime that let you get the list of ivars, properties, and methods associated with a given class, and then to get information about individual ivars, properties, and methods. Take a look at the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Nice list of functions but that was not exactly what I needed, thanks anyway.