# Is the ivar required for properties where @synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;

Tags: objective-c, properties

In the following example, is the line `NSObject *_propertyName;` required?

.h

```
@interface  ClassName
{
    NSObject *_propertyName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *propertyName;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation  ClassName

@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;

@end
```

I find that if I exclude `NSObject *_propertyName;` but keep `@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;` everything works.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

.h

```
@interface  ClassName

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *propertyName;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation  ClassName

@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;

@end
```

I've tested and seen that the property still works.  I nearly always see code that includes the line `NSObject *_propertyName;`.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Please do a search before posting. There's already a gazillion and a half questions that cover this. Here's one such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330257/is-it-necessary-to-declare-ivars-in-interface-to-match-properties

Comment: Here's a search that will turn up more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+declare+ivars+for+properties Some of these are in the Related sidebar to the right, and would have come up when you were drafting your question.

Comment: I did a lot of searching before posting this answer.  None of the other questions came up.  Sorry for the repost, but I really tried to find an answer.

Comment: So, in retrospect, I must have not been searching for the right phrase.  I'll be more creative in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything. Starting with the newer runtimes (newer iOS Simulator, x86_64 and ARM) you no longer need to manually declare an ivar. Prior to that on i386 and PPC you had to manually declare your ivars.