# Objective C - Defining an instance variable when defining a property

Tags: objective-c

I saw this code snippet on the Internet (http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/outlets-property-vs-instance-variable.html):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
 UILabel *myLabel;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

My question is...When @synthesize is called isn't the UILabel instance variable created automatically? What is the point of creating the instance variable in the header file.. Can you get away with just the @property?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties and Instance Variables in Objective-C 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074248/properties-and-instance-variables-in-objective-c-2-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When @synthesize is called isn't the UILabel instance variable created automatically?

Yes.

> What is the point of creating the instance variable in the header file.

Personal preference.  Some developers (like me) prefer to see a complete picture of the state of a class.  It helps to see what instance variables are available, as well as check that all instance variables are released correctly.

It's also a relatively new feature.  Older code wouldn't expect automatically-generated instance variables.

> Can you get away with just the @property?

No, you need to `@synthesize` to get an automatically generated instance variables  A property value that's generated programmatically would not map directly to any instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

@synthesize will create the instance variable but you will not be able to see it in the debugger which can be downright inconvenient.

Consider filing a bug with Apple about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get away with just the `@property` in Objective-c 2.0.

see: [Do declared properties require a corresponding instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074248/properties-and-instance-variables-in-objective-c-2-0)