# what is the difference between writing with/without variables declaration

Tags: iphone, properties, instance-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Properties and Instance Variables in Objective-C 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074248/properties-and-instance-variables-in-objective-c-2-0)

I wrote the codes below, both worked on xcode 3/ios4 and xcode 4/ios5

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface testViewController : UIViewController {

NSString *s;

}
@property (retain ,nonatomic) NSString *s;
@end
```

the one without variables declaration

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface testViewController : UIViewController {



}
@property (retain ,nonatomic) NSString *s;
@end
```

and

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface testViewController : UIViewController {

NSString *s;

}
```

what is the difference between writing with/without variables declaration

As I know @property means replacing/simplfying the method setter/getter of the property.
Does the variable declaration in { } means private property that can not be accessed outside testViewController?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare property without related ivar, compiler injects it by default. The one difference is that implicit ivar is invisible in derived classes and outside your class.